# Override Object.toString Error

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, flash-builder, overriding, tostring

Why does this produce an error in Flash Builder?:

```flex
package {
  public class Foo {
    override public function toString():String {
      return "Foo";
    }
  }
}
```

Tab completion suggests that this is available for override...

**Error message:**

```
Multiple markers at this line:
-public
-1020: Method marked override must override another method.
-overridesObject.toString
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Remove `override` on the `toString()` method.

There is a popular misconception among about the `toString()` method, namely: if one wants to provide a custom implementation of a super class method, the `override` keyword is needed. But in case of `Object`, `toString()` is dynamic and is attached at runtime, negating the need for overriding. Instead, the implementation is to be provided by the developer so one is not created at runtime. One just needs to write their own `toString():String` implementation.

Comment: You are right, dynamic properties are late-bound. `Properties that you add to an instance of a dynamic class are run-time entities...` ([Livedocs - Dynamic Classes](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=03_Language_and_Syntax_10.html))

Answer (score 0):

Foo is not extending a class; so therefore there are no methods to override.  Just remove the override keyword from the function definition and it should compile

```
package {
  public class Foo {
    public function toString():String {
      return "Foo";
    }
  }
}
```

I'll add that [toString()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Object.html#toString%28%29) is a method of the [Object](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Object.html) class which many ActionScript classes extend from.  But, even if you extend Object, you don't need to override the toString() method. From the docs:

> To redefine this method in a subclass of Object, do not use the
>   override keyword.

Like this:

```
package {
  public class Foo extends Object {
    public function toString():String {
      return "Foo";
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Weird... I tried explicitly extending Object and it still complained.

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl I edited my answer a bit.  Even when extending Object; you don't need to use override.  That was my bad.