# Inherited methods not actually getting called

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-cs6

I'm creating a Flash Game using Adobe's Flash Pro CS6, and I have hit a blunder. I'm making an endless runner and I need to randomly generate blocks for the player to jump over and duck under. Coming from a Java background, this generally should work fairly easily, however it doesn't. Here are my three classes, `Box.as`, `GroundBox.as`, and `RoofBox.as` in separate files (SOs code formatting combines them):

```
// Box.as:
package  {
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    public class Box extends MovieClip {
        public static function getDefaultY():Number {
            return 258.75;
        }
        public function myToString():String {
            return "Box[" + this.x + "," + this.y + "]";
        }
    }
}

// GroundBox.as:
package {
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    public class GroundBox extends Box {
        public function collidesWith(xPos:Number, yPos:Number):Boolean {
            return this.x <= xPos && xPos <= this.x + this.width && this.y <= yPos && yPos <= this.y + this.height;
        }
    }
}

// RoofBox.as:
package {
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    public class RoofBox extends Box {
        public function collidesWith(xPos:Number, yPos:Number):Boolean {
            return this.x <= xPos && xPos <= this.x + this.width && this.y >= yPos && yPos >= this.y - this.height;
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, I have my super class `Box` which has two functions: `public static function getDefaultY():Number` and `public function myToString():String` (it's called 'myToString' because I got errors when trying to override 'toString'). The problems I am having are that when I create a `var gBox:GroundBox = new GroundBox();`, I can't call `gBox.y = Box.getDefaultY();` or `trace(gBox.myToString());`.

The error codes given:

```
TypeError: Error #1006: getDefaultY is not a function.
    at Dude_fla::MainTimeline/frame1()
TypeError: Error #1006: myToString is not a function.
    at Dude_fla::MainTimeline/updateBlocks()[Dude_fla.MainTimeline::frame1:244]
    at Dude_fla::MainTimeline/updateLoop()[Dude_fla.MainTimeline::frame1:20]
```

Comment: you can't have more than one public class in a single as3 file, also since you don't have a constructor, the default constructor is run (`MovieClip`)

Comment: They're all in separate AS3 classes. SO handles code formatting like this...

Comment: oh okay, but the missing constructor is what probably causes your problem anyways

Comment: and about the `toString()` overriding, this might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18347026/override-object-tostring-error

Comment: @MartonPallagi, I think it was because Flash Pro let me save my AS3 scripts in a different directory, but didn't expect them to be elsewhere; it wanted the scripts next to the .fla file. Either that, or the constructor being missing was the problem. Either way, it's fixed. :D Cheers!

Comment: There might be a path problem and your box class is in fact autogenerated by flash and thus has no code. Btw a static method like getDefaultY() is not inherited.

Comment: So the problem is fixed, but there are no answers. What do we close this as?